# Creating a Python program that takes in a short description and returns a solution from a given set (using nlp)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk

I am trying to take a person's ailment, and return what they should do (from a predetermined set of "solutions").

For example,

#### person's ailment

```
My head is not bleeding
```

#### predetermined set of "solutions"

```
[take medicine, go to a doctor, call the doctor]
```

I know I need to first remove common words from the sentence (`such as 'my' and 'is'`) but also preserve "common" words such as 'not,' which are crucial to the solution and important to the context.

Next, I'm pretty sure I'll need to *train a set of processed inputs* and match them to outputs *to train a model* which will attempt to identify the "solution" for the given string.

Are there any other libraries I should be using (`other than nltk, and scikit-learn`)?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out `gensim`. and you might want to check out these keywords for a start: tokenizer, word stemming, lemmatization, good luck!